# Python - scalability with respect to run time and memory usage is important

Tags: python, generator, yield-keyword

I have python scripts to filter a massive data in csv file. The requirement asks for considering scalability with respect to run time and memory usage.

I wrote 2 scripts, both of them are working fine of filtering data. Regarding to considering scalability, I decided to use python generator, because it uses iterator and don't save much data in memory.

When I compared the running time of 2 scripts, I found the following:

script 1 - use generator - take more time - 0.0155925750732s

```
def each_sentence(text):
    match = re.match(r'[0-9]+', text)
    num = int(text[match.start():match.end()])
    if sympy.isprime(num) == False:
        yield text.strip()

with open("./file_testing.csv") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        for text in each_sentence(line):
            print(text)
```

script 2 - use split and without generator - take less time - 0.00619888305664

```
with open("./file_testing.csv") as csvfile:
for line in csvfile:
    array = line.split(',')
    num = int(array[0])
    if sympy.isprime(num) == False:
        print line.strip()
```

To meet the requirement, do I need to use python generator? or any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: How big is your data? Iteration will always be faster with a small dataset, compared to yield.

Comment: @Daniel Scott my data can go up to 1 billion, it is quite large

Comment: Okay. I've updated my answer for you. Gusi Gao has a great suggestion about threading the bottleneck. If that's in the scope of your question, you should consider his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To meet the requirement, do I need to use python generator?

No, you don't. Script 1 doesn't make sense. The generator is always executed once and return one result in the first iteration.

> Any suggestions or recommendations?

You need to learn about three things: complexity, parallelization and caching.

- Complexity basically means "if I double the size of input data (csv file), do I need twice the time? Or four times? Or what"?
- Parallelization means attacking a problem in a way that makes it easy to add more resources for solving it.
- Caching is important. Things get much faster if you don't have to re-create everything all the time, but you can re-use stuff you have already generated.

The main loop `for line in csvfile:` already scales very well unless the csv file contains extremely long lines.

Script 2 contains a bug: If the first cell in a line is not integer, then `int(array[0])` will raise a value error.

The `isprime` function is probably the "hotspot" in your code, so you can try to parallelize it with multiple threads or sub-processes.

Comment: I know we are able to use multiple-threading by calling function `Pool` and `map`, but `sympy.isprime(num)` is function with a single input number, how could I do it with multiple threading?

Comment: Another question, I try to read 100 lines each time, use 4 threads to filter 100 lines and find the prime, and turned out it took longer to finish, do I expect it to finish early ?

Comment: Everytime you call pool(), it will continue blocking the parent thread (not necessarily Main() though) until the result is finished. So if one particular thread took a really long time compared to others (if say a massive 'match' result occurs), the pool() call would block until the longest process completed. Does that help clarify things?

Comment: In short, you would not finish early.

Answer (score 1):

Split your analysis into two discrete regular expression results: A small result with 10 values, and a large result with 10,000,000 values. This question is about the average `len()` of `match`, as much as it is about the `len()` of `csvfile`.

## With a small re result - 10 bytes

1st code block will have slower run time, and relatively *low memory usage*.

2nd code block will have faster run time, and also relatively *low memory usage*.

## With a large re result - 10,000,000 bytes

1st code block will have slower run time, and *very little* memory usage.

2nd code block will have faster run time, and **very large** memory usage.

## Bottom line:

If you are supposed to build a function considering run time and memory, then the yield function is definitely the best way to go when the problem requires a scalable solution to different result sizes.

Another question on scalability: What if the re result equals None? I would slightly modify the code to below:

```
def each_sentence(text):
    match = re.match(r'[0-9]+', text)
    if match != None:
        num = int(text[match.start():match.end()])
        if sympy.isprime(num) == False:
            yield text.strip()

with open("./file_testing.csv") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        for text in each_sentence(line):
            print(text)
```